# How to get return from f.stat()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
fs.readdir(directorypath, function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error getting directory information.")
  } 
  else {
    var results = [];
    files.forEach((file) => {

      fs.stat(directorypath + `\\${file}`, (err, stats) => {
        var modifiedTime = stats.mtime;
        var size = (stats.size) / (1024 * 1024);
        results.push({
          Time: modifiedTime,
          size: size
        });
      });
    });
    res.json(results);
  }

});
```

I am getting results as empty array even if there are files the directory

Comment: `fs.stat()` is an **asynchronous** API. Results are not made available immediately.

Comment: You could use `fs.statSync()`.

Comment: shouldn't that be a forward slash before the file in the string interpolation?

Comment: @danh If it's Windows you can use either.